# How to change mysql password

Tags: mysql

I am on OS X 10.9.5 and I did a reinstall of mysql2 and I provided a password during installation but it is not working when I run the command `mysql -uroot -p`. The result I get is: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Does someone know how I can reset the mysql password? I have been searching posts all day on how to fix my issues but nothing has helped.

Comment: OK, have you tried "mysql -u root -pmy_password"? Notice the space between -u and root and the lack of space between -p and the password. Finally, what is "mysql2"? If the worse comes to the worst, maybe you might have to reinstall?

Comment: I never did it without the space, but it gave the same result when I did it with the space: `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I will do another reinstall I guess since I have explored every other option it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the exact steps I had to run to get it working:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

In new terminal:

```
mysql -u root  

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('my-new-password') WHERE User='root';  
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;  

\q

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: Why stop the MySQL server? Imagine it is a production instance and should not be stopped for such a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The steps for changing your root password are [laid out in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). Since you're on OS X, follow the instructions under section "B.5.4.1.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems"

Comment: Thanks. But I have read a lot of articles and posts, none have helped. I have been to those docs. And I ran into the error: `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`. I could be missing steps, but I have tried so many different "solutions" but nothing has worked.

Comment: The key is the option  `--skip-grant-tables`.